# Which XBLA games have I purchased?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-live-arcade

My old xbox has passed on, but I don't have a list of all the XBLA games that I purchased.  Is it possible to find such a list somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried looking in your xbox.com purchase history??

Comment: perfect, thats it.  I haven't been to xbox.com in years, iirc this wasn't here before.  Thanks!

Comment: next, how do I mark this as answered, since James Jiao didn't put an answer, just a comment?

Comment: @justing You can't mark a comment as an answer but he _can_ make an answer saying the same thing for you to mark that as correct.

Comment: Ok made it an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all your past purchases under your Xbox purchase history (navigatable via the My Account page) on the xbox.com website. See screenshot.

[image: My account page]